# Adding routes for Smfony 6 bundle, without add resource to main application

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I am trying to create a Symfony bundle which has some controllers and routes.

Here is the basic deninition of the bundle:

`bundles/PaypalBundle/src/PaypalBundle.php`

```php
<?php

namespace XXX\PaypalBundle;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\Configurator\ContainerConfigurator;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\AbstractBundle;

class PaypalBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
    public function prependExtension(ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        $container->extension('twig', [
            'paths' => [
                '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/xxx/paypal-bundle/templates' => 'PaypalBundle',
            ],
        ]);

        // some more service deninitions....

        $services = $container->services();
        $services->defaults()
            ->autowire()
            ->autoconfigure()
        ;
        $services->load('XXX\\PaypalBundle\\Controller\\', '../src/Controller')
            ->tag('controller.service_arguments')
        ;
    }
}
```

and I have this file:

`bundles/PaypalBundle/config/routes.yaml`

```yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

Now to test my controllers and route I need to add:

```yaml
paypalBundle_routes:
  resource: '@PaypalBundle/config/routes.yaml'
```

in my `config/routes.yaml` in my main application where this bundle is installed.

This works, and I can access the route after the bundle is installed.

**Now what I want is that when this bundle is installed or uninstalled it should atuomaitcally add the route resources to my main application**

Here is my controller look like:

```php
#[Route('/{_locale}/paypal/betsellungsvermerk', name: 'xxx_paypalBundle_paymentNotification', requirements: ['_locale' => '%app_locales%'])]
    public function isPaid(PayPalService $payPalFactory): Response
    {
        $return = $payPalFactory->checkOrderingIsPaid();

        $response = new Response(json_encode($return, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

        return $response;
    }
```

I tried adding this in my PaypalBundle:

```php
public function loadExtension(array $config, ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        $yamlFileLoad = new \Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader(new \Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../config'));
        $routes = $yamlFileLoad->load('routes.yaml');
        $builder->addDefinitions($routes->getResources());
    }
```

But it doesnt work : `Cannot load resource "../src/Controller/". Make sure there is a loader supporting the "annotation" type.`

> I dont want to use Symfony Flex

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a Flex recipe? Also, are you sure this problem is directly related to Composer?

Comment: No, its not related to composer I think. But I do install it witch composer. How can I use Flex recipe? Thanks